# Maximize the number of uniform width cells in table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I would like to create a table using divs where each row holds a maximum number of uniformly sized cells based on the text content in the cells.  In the end, I will load an array of strings using AJAX.  I would like to be able to determine what the maximum cell width would be for the longest string if the browser were to render them apriori, and then use that information to calculate the max number of cells to place in a row if all the cells were to have the width sized to the maximum.

I've run into problems calculating the size of a the max cell since I'm dynamically generating them and inserting them into a table the 'width' function always returns 0 since they have not yet been rendered.

An example of what I would like to do conceptually is like so:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.dtable {display: table;}
.drow {display: table-row;}       
.dcell { 
    font-family:Consolas,'Lucida Console','DejaVu Sans Mono',monospace;
    display: table-cell; padding: 10px; outline:black solid thin; background-color: yellow;
}
.dcell > * {vertical-align: middle; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        var w = $('#qcell2').width();
        alert(w);

        $('#qcell4').width(w);
        $('#qcell5').width(w);
        $('#qcell6').width(w);
    }); // end document-ready callback
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="qblock" class="dtable" style="margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%;">
        <div id="qrow" class="drow" style="">
            <div id="qcell1" class="dcell">text</div>
            <div id="qcell2" class="dcell">a lot more text</div>
            <div id="qcell3" class="dcell">some text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="qblock" class="dtable" style="margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%;"> 
        <div id="qrow" class="drow">
            <div id="qcell4" class="dcell">text</div>
            <div id="qcell5" class="dcell">a lot more text</div>
            <div id="qcell6" class="dcell">some text</div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: I made a screenshot available here]

Notice I let the browser render three cells in one table, and since I can visually see that #qcell2 is the longest, I draw a second table setting all the widths to what I determine the width from #qcell2 to be.  Since I can let the browser first render all the cells and the table is amply wide such that the browser is not trying to compress the cells I get what a comfortable maximum width for all the cells should be.  I want to use that info to now calculate how many cells per row I can draw such that they are all uniformly sized and use all the real estate available to the table.

Again, ultimately, I will begin with a simple array of strings and create a table with cells for as many of the strings as I can comfortably place in the table such that they are all uniformly sized to be the size of the cell holding the widest string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a table, use `<table>`. It does everything you need, without using any javascript!

There's nothing wrong with tables as long as you use them for displaying tabular data.